# use .assign() method with lambda in python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, lambda, assign

I run this code in Python:

```
 #Declaring these now for later use in the plots
 TOP_CAP_TITLE = 'Top 10 market capitalization'
 TOP_CAP_YLABEL = '% of total cap'

 # Selecting the first 10 rows and setting the index
 cap10 = cap.loc[:10, :].set_index('id')

 # Calculating market_cap_perc
 cap10 = cap10.assign(market_cap_perc =
      lambda x: (x.market_cap_usd / cap.market_cap_usd.sum()) * 100)
 # Plotting the barplot with the title defined above 
 ax = cap10.plot.bar(x= id, y= market_cap_perc)
 ax.set_title(TOP_CAP_TITLE)
 # Annotating the y axis with the label defined above
 ax.set_ylabel(TOP_CAP_YLABEL)
```

And getting an error:

```
NameError Traceback (most recent call last) in ()
   10 lambda x: (x.market_cap_usd / cap.market_cap_usd.sum()) * 100) 
   11 # Plotting the barplot with the title defined above ---> 
   12 ax = cap10.plot.bar(x= id, y= market_cap_perc) 
   13 ax.set_title(TOP_CAP_TITLE) 
   14 # Annotating the y axis with the label defined above
NameError: name 'market_cap_perc' is not defined
```

Thats code from Task4 on DataCamp Project Exploring the Bitcoin cryptocurrency market. `cap` is DataFrame with column `id`(such as 'bitcoin', 'ripple'). Another column `market_cap_usd` (this column consist cost of cryptocurrency market in usd. For example, '159640995719' - its a `market_cap_usd` for bitcoin). 
There are instructions to complete this task:

1.Select the first 10 coins, set the index to `id`, and assign the resulting DataFrame to `cap10`.

2.Calculate the percentage of market capitalization for each coin using `assign()` and assign it to `cap10` again.

3.Plot the top 10 coin's `market_cap_perc` in a barplot with the title "Top 10 market capitalization" and assign it to `ax`.

4.Using the `ax` object, annotate the y axis with "% of total cap".

I try to define market_cap_perc before lambda:
`market_cap_perc = 0`
and get an error:

```
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)

    2133             try:
->  2134                 return self._engine.get_loc(key)
    2135             except KeyError:

pandas/index.pyx in pandas.index.IndexEngine.get_loc (pandas/index.c:4443)()

pandas/index.pyx in pandas.index.IndexEngine.get_loc (pandas/index.c:4289)()

KeyError: 139887424317984
```

Comment: It's not the lambda that causes the issue, but the `ax = cap10.plot.bar(x= id, y= market_cap_perc)` line further down. The line in the *middle* of the traceback section.

Comment: Nowhere in your code have you set the name `market_cap_perc`, so you can't pass it into that call either.

Comment: Looks like you failed to define `market_cap_perc` elsewhere in your code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answer:

```
import pandas as pd
# Reading datasets/coinmarketcap_06122017.csv into pandas
dec6 = pd.read_csv('datasets/coinmarketcap_06122017.csv')

# Selecting the 'id' and the 'market_cap_usd' columns
market_cap_raw = dec6[['id','market_cap_usd']]
cap = market_cap_raw.query('market_cap_usd > 0')
#Declaring these now for later use in the plots
TOP_CAP_TITLE = 'Top 10 market capitalization'
TOP_CAP_YLABEL = '% of total cap'

# Selecting the first 10 rows and setting the index
cap10 = cap.head(10).set_index('id')

# Calculating market_cap_perc
cap10 = cap10.assign(market_cap_perc = lambda x:   (x.market_cap_usd/cap.market_cap_usd.sum())*100)

# Plotting the barplot with the title defined above 
ax = cap10.market_cap_perc.head(10).plot.bar(title=TOP_CAP_TITLE)

# Annotating the y axis with the label defined above
ax.set_ylabel(TOP_CAP_YLABEL)
```